# How to notify for problems when implementing custom rollback?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I'm using `ADO.NET EF` and I need to implement some sort of custom rollback in my `Save()` method. The logic is this

- I have an `OpenFileDialog` and the first step when `Save()` is called is to check if there is selected image and if there is to copy the selected image to a new location.
- Then I set the properties for the entity including the picture name (which is the reason I choose to copy the image first) and check if there is no duplication of unique values with this method : `HasDuplicatingEntity(entity)`
- If the copy process went well and there is no entity with the same unique value just then I save the entity itself : `Save(entity)`
- If something went wrong with `Save(entity)` I just have to delete the previously copied image (if there is such) and that's it.

The actual implementation is something like this:

```
try
{
  SaveImage();
  if(HasDuplicatingEntity(entity))
  {  
    //Show message to the user
    return false;
  }
  Save(entity);
}
catch
{
  //Log the exception and show message
  //Delete the image if there is such
}
```

The problem that occurs is that if I try to save a new entity with chosen image but `HasDuplicatingEntity(entity)` returns true. Then with the current logic I just show the user that there is already an entity with the same unique value and then just return false which, in the cases when an image is selected and then copied, leaves me with an unused image in my file system.

Which leads me to my exact question. I have a method that is meant to delete the image in case of some problem but it's called in the `catch` clause. Now when I see that there is another place where I might need to delete an image I see two options - just calling the method from within the `if` :

```
if(HasDuplicatingEntity(entity))
      {  
        //Show message to the user
        //Delete Image
        return false;
      }
```

Which is kinda logical but except the method call I have some checks to find out if there is in fact a copied image, because the image is not required and that will result in a few line of repeating code. The other option is to throw exception and go to the `catch` clause where I already deal with this problem but that means to change the current way this situation is managed. This exact part :

```
if(HasDuplicatingEntity(entity))
      {  
        //Show message to the user
        return false;
      }
```

is inherited and I don't have much experience so I don't want to turn something good to something bad so I want to know which is the correct way to deal with this issue.